How do I share my Google Form document with other collaborators with only the link?
Is there a way to share my Google Forms document with other editors that do not have a Google account by sending them a collaboration link? That is, without inviting them to the document via a pre-made Google invite email.
As of now, I have already switched the "General Access" to "everyone that has access to this link." But when I copy the link and send it to an email address that is not linked to a Google account, I do not get editing access; rather, I can just answer the questions in the form. 

You are not sending the correct link.
You are either copying

The "Responders Link" which only allows you to fill out the form, or
The normal editing link that authenticates based on a Google account.

If you want users to be completely logged out of a Google account you need to go through the process of specifying an email address and sending a link. You could send it to yourself if you have a non-Google email address and then copy the link from that email and share.
Ideally, you would send a new link directly from Forms to each non-Google user so that you can manage their permissions separately if you want to shut off access to one but not another.
